# Problem in capacitor selection

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, pcb, gsm, esr

[The SIM800L datasheet](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) suggesting a low ESR capacitor for providing a 2 ampere burst current during data transmission.

[According to this site](https://passive-components.eu/why-low-esr-matters-in-capacitor-design/?fbclid=IwAR2TeN9l3qLleH06BlOrsqREWo8NWONN296OuzVTsngtcMHVKHtScqqbf0U) MLCC provides the lowest ESR at high-frequency application, and Al polymer provides low ESR at low-frequency application.

What I am confused about is that the GSM will transmit data at a significant interval of time (60 seconds). This means a step response would occur at a 60-second interval.

Which capacitor should I use?

This is not a high-frequency application, but a step response contains a lot of high-frequency components.

Comment: A quick search of boards that use this module have a 47uF tant. If you decide to use ceramic caps, be aware of the voltage derating in that the actual capacitance you get depends on the DC voltage. This means you may require a number of capacitors to achieve the required capcitance.

Comment: Also suggest using a wider package for lower ESL, ie. 1210 not 1206.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the high current pulses will be a few milliseconds long, so you’ll want a capacitor, or perhaps a bank of capacitors that can source 2A for a short period without significant voltage drop.  If you have a switch mode converter driving the modem then the output-side capacitor only needs to maintain the supply for as long as the switcher needs to respond, and then the input to the switcher needs to store enough energy to keep the modem supplied, but the ripple voltage may be substantially higher than what the modem can tolerate.  In my experience using similar devices, a fairly large SMT ceramic will do, perhaps 22 to 100uF.